# How to automate vertical bar chart labels?

Tags: r

I would like to automate data labels (with % signs) placed on top of the vertical bars produced with the code below. Is there a way to do this?

```
H <- c(61,89,94,89) # Create the data for the chart.#
M <- c("Pre-Calculus",
       "College Algebra",
       "Intermediate Algebra",
       "Elementary Algebra")

par(mar=c(5.1, 10, 4, 1.1))
barplot(H, col =c("dodgerblue4" ),  ylim = range(0,110),
        names.arg = M, horiz = F, 
        family="Arial", border = NA, xlim = range(0,5), las=1,
        axes = T, ylab = 'Passing Percent')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `text()` function. See [this SO post for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134623/text-in-barplot-in-r)

```
bp <- barplot(H, col =c("dodgerblue4" ),  ylim = range(0,110),
        names.arg = M, horiz = F, 
        family="Arial", border = NA, xlim = range(0,5), las=1,
        axes = T, ylab = 'Passing Percent')

text(bp, H + 5, paste(H, "%", sep=""))
```